Macro for circular representations of integer partitions
I would like a TikZ macro that takes as input an integer partition such as (3, 2, 2) and produces the figure on the left below and another macro that produces the figure on the right below.

Because the sketches are very sloppy, let me describe them.  Write (p_1, ..., p_t) for an arbitrary partition of n (so ∑ p_i = n).
On the left in the "sector diagram," each part p_i corresponds to one of t equal sectors.  The sector for p_i is divided into p_i pieces by p_i - 1 equally spaced arcs.
On the right in the "ring diagram," each part p_i corresponds to a ring divided into p_i equal pieces.  The outer ring is p_1, immediately inside it is the p_2 ring, with p_t a circle at the center.
In both figures, there are a total of n regions (7 in the examples).  The sectors and ring divisions all start at "12 o'clock."
It would be a nice add-on if selected regions could be shaded.
Background: These integer partition representations were explored by the mathematical artist Margaret Kepner.
Edit: added WheelChart tag.

Here is a process that works: 1. start very simple, 2. refactor, 3. add a small change, repeat at #2. E.g. you could start with a simple drawing, like a circle and work towards parameters, e.g. by introducing \newcommand(s). I described refactoring here several times: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A245790+refactoring+ . Enjoy its magic, resulting in cleaner and more capable code.

The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
Two commands are defined: \partitionA and \partitionB. These commands take 2 arguments. The first argument is the partition. The second argument is a list of colors.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__Hopkins_list_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \partitionA { m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn {##2}
          {
            \int_incr:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
            \wheelchart
              [
                data = ,
                radius = { ( ####1 - 1 ) / ##2 } { ####1 / ##2 } ,
                slices~style = { \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int } , draw = black , thick } ,
                start~angle = 90 - ( ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} ) * 360 ,
                total~angle = 360 / \clist_count:n {#1}
              ]
              { 1 }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \partitionB { m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \wheelchart
          [
            radius = { 1 - ##1 / \clist_count:n {#1} } { 1 - ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} } ,
            slices~style = { \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int + \WCcount } , draw = black , thick } ,
            total~count = ##2
          ]
          {}
        \int_add:Nn \l__Hopkins_index_int {##2}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\partitionA{3,2,2}{orange,magenta,olive,teal,cyan,purple,violet}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2.5)}]
\partitionB{3,2,2}{orange,magenta,olive,teal,cyan,purple,violet}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,0)}]
\partitionA{2,4,5,3}{blue,brown,cyan,gray,lime,magenta,olive,orange,pink,purple,red,teal,violet,yellow}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-2.5)}]
\partitionB{2,4,5,3}{blue,brown,cyan,gray,lime,magenta,olive,orange,pink,purple,red,teal,violet,yellow}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Added a gray scale version as suggested by Sigur.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__Hopkins_list_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \partitionA { m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn {##2}
          {
            \int_incr:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
            \wheelchart
              [
                data = ,
                radius = { ( ####1 - 1 ) / ##2 } { ####1 / ##2 } ,
                slices~style = { black ! \fp_eval:n { ( ( ##2 + 1 - ####1 ) / ( ##2 + 1 ) ) * 100 } , draw = black , thick } ,
                start~angle = 90 - ( ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} ) * 360 ,
                total~angle = 360 / \clist_count:n {#1}
              ]
              { 1 }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \partitionB { m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \wheelchart
          [
            radius = { 1 - ##1 / \clist_count:n {#1} } { 1 - ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} } ,
            slices~style = { black ! \fp_eval:n { ( ##1 / ( \clist_count:n {#1} + 1 ) ) * 100 } , draw = black , thick } ,
            total~count = ##2
          ]
          {}
        \int_add:Nn \l__Hopkins_index_int {##2}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\partitionA{3,2,2}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2.5)}]
\partitionB{3,2,2}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,0)}]
\partitionA{2,4,5,3}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-2.5)}]
\partitionB{2,4,5,3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Added a number in each region as suggested by Brian Hopkins. This is achieved with the keys wheel data and wheel data pos.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__Hopkins_list_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \partitionA { m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn {##2}
          {
            \int_incr:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
            \wheelchart
              [
                data = ,
                radius = { ( ####1 - 1 ) / ##2 } { ####1 / ##2 } ,
                slices~style = { \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int } , draw = black , thick } ,
                start~angle = 90 - ( ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} ) * 360 ,
                total~angle = 360 / \clist_count:n {#1} ,
                wheel~data = \int_use:N \l__Hopkins_index_int ,
                wheel~data~pos = 0.5
              ]
              { 1 }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \partitionB { m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \wheelchart
          [
            radius = { 1 - ##1 / \clist_count:n {#1} } { 1 - ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} } ,
            slices~style = { \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int + \WCcount } , draw = black , thick } ,
            total~count = ##2 ,
            wheel~data = \int_eval:n { \l__Hopkins_index_int + \WCcount } ,
            wheel~data~pos = 0.5
          ]
          {}
        \int_add:Nn \l__Hopkins_index_int {##2}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\partitionA{3,2,2}{orange,magenta,olive,teal,cyan,purple,violet}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2.5)}]
\partitionB{3,2,2}{orange,magenta,olive,teal,cyan,purple,violet}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,0)},font=\tiny]
\partitionA{2,4,5,3}{blue,brown,cyan,gray,lime,magenta,olive,orange,pink,purple,red,teal,violet,yellow}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-2.5)},font=\tiny]
\partitionB{2,4,5,3}{blue,brown,cyan,gray,lime,magenta,olive,orange,pink,purple,red,teal,violet,yellow}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Interesting. What about a gray scale version? For example, compute the number of sectors and use shades of gray, darker in the center and lighter on the border.

@Sigur See the updated answer.

Excellent answer.

Wonderful, thanks so much.

@matexmatics Apologies for adding to my wishlist, but is it easy to place a number in each region?  Similar to the way a Young tableaux is a Young diagram with a number in each box, it would be nice to place the numbers 1..7 to the (3,2,2) figure one per region in any way.  Looking at the WheelChart documentation, this seems feasible, but the way you've (wonderfully) combined things for this answer, I don't see easily how to accomplish this.

@Sebastiano Thank you!

@BrianHopkins See the updated answer.

@matexmatics Thanks much. I was able to modify your new code to allow arbitrary labels (shared as an answer below).

@BrianHopkins You're welcome.

For convenience, I'm including the code below, combining both examples shared by @matexmatics into a single file.
\documentclass[border=6pt, multi=page]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__Hopkins_list_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \partitionA { m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn {##2}
          {
            \int_incr:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
            \wheelchart
              [
                data = ,
                radius = { ( ####1 - 1 ) / ##2 } { ####1 / ##2 },
                slices~style = { \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int }, draw = black, thick },
                start~angle = 90 - ( ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} ) * 360,
                total~angle = 360 / \clist_count:n {#1}
              ]
              { 1 }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \partitionB { m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \wheelchart
          [
            radius = { 1 - ##1 / \clist_count:n {#1} } { 1 - ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} } ,
            slices~style = { \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int + \WCcount }, draw = black, thick } ,
            total~count = ##2
          ]
          {}
        \int_add:Nn \l__Hopkins_index_int {##2}
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \partitionC { m }
  {
  \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
    {
      \int_step_inline:nn {##2}
        {
          \int_incr:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
          \wheelchart
            [
              data = ,
              radius = { ( ####1 - 1 ) / ##2 } { ####1 / ##2 },
              slices~style = { black ! \fp_eval:n { ( ( ##2 + 1 - ####1 ) / ( ##2 + 1 ) ) * 100 }, draw = black, thick },
              start~angle = 90 - ( ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} ) * 360,
              total~angle = 360 / \clist_count:n {#1}
            ]
            { 1 }
        }
    }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \partitionD { m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
      {
        \wheelchart
          [
            radius = { 1 - ##1 / \clist_count:n {#1} } { 1 - ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} },
            slices~style = { black ! \fp_eval:n { ( ##1 / ( \clist_count:n {#1} + 1 ) ) * 100 }, draw = black, thick },
            total~count = ##2
          ]
          {}
        \int_add:Nn \l__Hopkins_index_int {##2}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{page}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \partitionA{3,2,2}{
        orange, magenta, olive,
        teal, cyan,
        purple, violet
    }
        
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2.5)}]
        \partitionB{3,2,2}{
            orange, magenta, olive,
            teal, cyan,
            purple, violet
        }
    \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,0)}]
            \partitionA{2,4,5,3}{
                blue, brown,
                cyan, gray, lime, magenta,
                olive, orange, pink, purple, red,
                teal, violet, yellow
        }
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-2.5)}]
            \partitionB{2,4,5,3}{
                blue, brown,
                cyan, gray, lime, magenta,
                olive, orange, pink, purple, red,
                teal, violet, yellow
            }
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{page}

\begin{page}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \partitionC{3,2,2}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2.5)}]
        \partitionD{3,2,2}
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,0)}]
        \partitionC{2,4,5,3}
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,-2.5)}]
        \partitionD{2,4,5,3}
    \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{page}

\end{document}


In case it's helpful to someone else, here is my modification of @matexmatics third answer that allows for arbitrary labels (and no colors).  This again uses the wonderful WheelChart package.  The two arguments are an integer partition and a list of labels.  (The example corresponds to a valid Young tableau but does not work as a labeled sector diagram since, going clockwise, part of the sector labeled 3 shares a boundary with the sector labeled 2.)
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__Hopkins_list_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \SectorLabeled { m m }
  {
  \int_zero:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Hopkins_list_seq
    {
        \int_step_inline:nn {##2}
          {
            \int_incr:N \l__Hopkins_index_int
            \wheelchart
              [
                data = ,
                radius = { ( ####1 - 1 ) / ##2 } { ####1 / ##2 } ,
                slices~style = { white , draw = black , thick } ,
                start~angle = 90 - ( ( ##1 - 1 ) / \clist_count:n {#1} ) * 360 ,
                total~angle = 360 / \clist_count:n {#1} ,
                wheel~data = \clist_item:nn {#2} { \l__Hopkins_index_int },
                wheel~data~pos = 0.5
              ]
              { 1 }
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SectorLabeled{3,2,2}{1,3,4,2,6,5,7}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


